# Appsflyer integration - out of store apk with React Native

Tags: react-native, appsflyer, appsflyer-android-sdk

I am trying with Appsflyer out of store apk integration with React Native, I have followed below mentioned steps -

- Added app on Appsflyer account with com.reactnativetest package and 9apps_int as channel name.
- Integrated react-native-appsflyer SDK in my React Native App, following the react-native-appsflyer documentation.
- Have added initSDK with debug mode true and trackEvent Method in the code.
- Have debug the app on phone, and I got the success response from initSDK and trackEvent.

Now when I look at the Appsflyer dashboard, it gives me "0" Organic & Non-Organic Install and there is no event also tracked in the dashboard.

I have also done the testing with AppsFlyer Integration Testing App, by whitelisting my device and testing the app again, but same result.

Please help me where I am wrong in this?

Do I need to upload the app on any store except play store/App store before testing, can't I test the app installs in debug mode?

Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you also test with URL with media and campaign?

[http://app.appsflyer.com/com.greatapp?pid=test&c=campaign_test_1&](https://support.appsflyer.com/hc/en-us/articles/115004703726-Best-Practice-for-Advanced-Testing-AppsFlyer-s-SDK)

I suppose at this stage it's easier to upload the app to the stores, you can always pull it back.